# Blender 2.79 cycles normal map bake artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normal-map

I am baking a normal map in Cycles and keep getting strange results, I do not know what am I doing wrong.

I tried baking in Cycles in tangent and object space, tried baking in BI in tangent and Object space.
The resulting map looks OK as far as I can tell, but I keep getting either completely or partially black render.

I tried all possible space options in Cycles material normal map node.
What am I missing?

[image]
[image: Normal map baking in Cycles problem]

Attachment: [Blend file](https://ufile.io/ioc6r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off Ambient Occlusion in World tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn, thanks! will do when I get back to PC. but why should AO affect surface normals? Is it a bug?

Comment: no, you just overexposure objects.